# Is it possible to compile and run C/C++ programme in Nokia N95?

Tags: c++, c, smartphone

I have a Nokia N95. Recently I found a Python interpreter for my phone. So I search for C++ compiler for my phone but in vain. Any C++ compiler is really available for my phone?

Answer (score 2):

Nokia N95 runs SymbianOS.  You can download the S60 3rd Edition SDK [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html).  It can be built using a [small selection of compilers](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/GCCE); the best one for you will probably be GCCE - an ARM cross compiler you can use on Windows.

The build process is simple enough but non-standard.  [This page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_do_I_start_programming_for_Symbian_OS%3F) should help you get started.

Comment: Also, have fun with [descriptors](http://www.symbiantutorial.org/symbian-tutorial/?3._Symbian_Fundamentals:3.6_Strings_and_Descriptors), which is Symbian's own take on the concept of strings.